# UDP Port Fowarding: channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, udp, socat

My situation is as follows:

I have currently trying to have a program between two Hosts send UDP packets over a SSH Tunnel. There is also a host intermediate between the two hosts. Note Server01 separates two subnets

Subnet: //// 10.11.X.X ///////// 192.168.X.X
Host: Client <------> Server01 <-----> Server02

[image]

I have successfully established a SSH connection and have used RSA key's so passwords are not needed.

I than followed this tutorial:

[SSH Port Forwarding for UDP](http://www.digitalinternals.com/network/ssh-port-forwarding-tcp-udp/365/)

In summary it tells me to use socat to configure a TCP-UDP relay on server01 by typing in:

```
server01$ socat tcp4-listen:8000,reuseaddr,fork udp:server02:53
```

and a UDP-TCP relay on the client using socat also:

```
client$ socat -T15 udp4-recvfrom:53000,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:8000
```

Now comes the problem. When I attempt to have my program create a socket on the localhost UDP Port 53000 and send data,

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

I believe my program is fine because when I put server02 on the same subnet as client my programs will exchange UDP packets perfectly.

Is there a setting I need to enable for my program to access the UDP port 53000 Socket? Or is it just impossible to create a socket on the UDP port because socat using it? I've been stuck on this for a while... Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I realized the program needed to be run as sudo so it could access the port... Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

EDITED: The c program I have needs sudo permission to connect a socket to the UDP PORT 53000 and to send packets through that port.

Comment: You shouldn't need root privileges (i.e. `sudo`) to open listening ports numbered above 1024.

Comment: @roaima I didn't use sudo to open listening ports. I needed sudo to allow my program to connect a socket to the UDP Port and send packets through.

Answer (score 1):

`socat` is  here to convert TCP to UDP

but in you explanation you dont talk about ssh

you must run ssh with `-L` to forward `client TCP 8000` to `server01 tcp 8000`

you must run something like 
 `ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000 server01` from your client